# Using sed to go to a specific line, change pattern then print all between line and another pattern

Tags: bash, sed, debian, gnu

So I need to change a specific line in a big textfile by something found one line before. What the text looks like:

> Nom: some text
>   Société: some text
>   Adresse: some text and numb3rs Code Postal: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] SOME TEXT
>   Tél. :
>   numbers
>   Fax :
>   numbers
>   "----------------------"

What I've found so far is (i believe i'm almost done):

```
K=0
while [ $K -lt 11519 ]; do
    let K=K+1
    L=`head -n $K file_that_contains_line_numbers_I_want.txt | tail -1`
    M=`expr $L - 2`
    dept=`head -n $L filename.txt | tail -1 | sed -e 's/Adresse:.*Code Postal: //' -e 's/[0-9]\{3\} .*//'`
    sed -n ""$M"{s/Tél. :/$dept/; /----------------------/p; q}" filename.txt >>newfile.csv
done
```

Where $dept is the first two digits after Code Postal: .
What doesn't yet work is the last sed bit: I want the end file to look like the old file, just with the "Tél." part changed to $dept.
New file:

> Nom: some text
>   Société: some text
>   Adresse: some text and numb3rs Code Postal: 90000 SOME TEXT
>   90
>   numbers
>   Fax :
>   numbers
>   "----------------------"

Obviously this pattern with the names repeat, but sometimes the lines Tél. and below are not there.

tl dr; I want to change a pattern in a file with something found one line up, with the thing found one line up changing.

If you found a different way to get $dept in a different line, I would be very happy to hear about it.

I know my code is not the least bit the most efficient, but I learned about sed one week ago only.

Thanks in advance for helping me/correcting me.

EDIT: As I've been asked to provide some input, here it is :

> Nom: JOHN DOE
>   Société: APERTURE SCIENCE
>   Adresse: 37 RUE OF PARIS CS 30112 Code Postal: 51726 REIMS CEDEX
>   Tél. :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   Fax :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"
>   Nom: OLIVER TWIST
>   Société: NASA
>   Adresse: 40 RUE DU GINGEMBRE CS 70999 Code Postal: 67009 STRASBOURG CEDEX
>   Tél. :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   Fax :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"
>   Nom: BARACK OBAMA
>   Société: WHITE HOUSE
>   Adresse: 124 BOULEVARD DE GAULLE Code Postal: 75017 PARIS
>   Tél. : 
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"

Output I want to achieve :

> Nom: JOHN DOE
>   Société: APERTURE SCIENCE
>   Adresse: 37 RUE OF PARIS CS 30112 Code Postal: 51726 REIMS CEDEX
>   51
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   Fax :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"
>   Nom: OLIVER TWIST
>   Société: NASA
>   Adresse: 40 RUE DU GINGEMBRE CS 70999 Code Postal: 67009 STRASBOURG CEDEX
>   67 
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   Fax :
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"
>   Nom: BARACK OBAMA
>   Société: WHITE HOUSE
>   Adresse: 124 BOULEVARD DE GAULLE Code Postal: 75017 PARIS
>   75 
>   12 34 56 78 90
>   "----------------------"

Comment: This isn't very clear, what are you replacing with what ?

Comment: Would be easier to use `awk`.

Comment: Is 11519 just a arbitrary number or are you actually looking for `while read -r L; do ... done<file_that_contains_line_numbers_I_want.txt`?

Comment: @tripleee ls 1159 is not an arbitrary number, it corresponds to the number of lines -1 containing the pattern Adresse: (where I can find my variable $dept).

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I would be very happy if you could help propose an answer using awk; however like I said, I believe I am almost done using sed so I wouldn't want to start everything from scratch plus having to learn awk.

Comment: @123 Sorry if I wasn't clear, to put it short I want to replace the "Tél." field with the two digits after "Code Postal:" which are a line before. I am sure there is a single sed command that can do that, but I'm no sed pro and I haven't find in my researches (on this website mainly, because it is a very helpful website) a way to do what I want.

Comment: @tripleee (apparently can't edit my previous comment anymore...) Could you explain what your code means ? I think it means to read line L (or K in this case) and put the content of that line in the variable L ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it does.  Reading an entire file with `head` and `tail` on line numbers inside a main loop is a frequent but completely atrocious antipattern.  You want to avoid that if there is a way.

Comment: Unfortunately you're not almost done, it just looks that way :-). Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some of the reasons why you should throw what you have so far away and start again with an awk script. Unfortuantely I can;t figure out from your question what you are trying to do - please just [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you very much for making me aware of that. As I said I am really a beginner in this field and I thought combining sed and a loop could help me because I haven't found yet a way to use sed to keep the pattern  found one line up and change the line after whit it. I am looking into the answers and trying to understand them.

Comment: @Biebelaskäse you are going in the wrong direction. I've been using sed for 35 years, awk for 25, I still use them both almost every day and sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. All of the sed constructs to do more than s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, people just use them today for the mental exercise not for production code (unless your goal is to create such horrendously incomprehensible code that you secure your job since no-one else can understand it).

Comment: wrt your newly added sample input: You said `sometimes the lines Tél. and below are not there.` - being able to handle those cases is a crucial requirement but you didn't include it in your sample input/output.

Comment: After proper checking, I have found that the line Tél. is always there, but I'm sure that the line Fax. and after are not always there; so there is no problem; thanks for the remark anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed :

```
$ sed '/.*Code Postal: \([0-9][0-9]\).*/{p;s//\1/;n;d}' file
Nom: some text
Société: some text
Adresse: some text and numb3rs Code Postal: 90000 SOME TEXT
90
numbers
Fax :
numbers
"----------------------"
```

- `/.*Code Postal: \([0-9][0-9]\).*/` : search for line containing `Code Postal:` followed by two digits
- `p` : print matching line (ie clone the line containing "Code Postal")
- `s//\1/` : substitute matching line (`s//\1`) with captured digits (`\([0-9][0-9]\)`)
- `n` read the next line ("Tél") and deletes it (`d`)

I've just seen your edit, you can achieve that with :

```
sed '/.*Code Postal: \([0-9][0-9]\).*/{p;s//\1/;N;/[0-9]/s/\n/ /;s/Tél\. : *//}' file
```

Note that the dept number will be output on a single line in the "OLIVER TWIST" block (because Tél.: is on a single line as in first block)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it works ! I would be very thankful if you could spare some time to explain to me what you did exactly, expecially the {p;s//\1/;n;d} part. I believe it starts like this : print; substitute nothing by occurence number 1 then n ? then delete; but as you can see, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide sample input to check against, but this should work:

```
/Code Postal:/ {
    match($0, /Code Postal: *([0-9][0-9])/, result);
    dept = result[1];
}

/^Tél/ { $2 = dept }

{ print }
```

Save the code to a file, then call `awk -f file input_file`. It works like this: If the line matches "Code Postal", then save the first two digits of the postal code in the variable `dept`. If the line starts with "Tél", replace the second field with the value of `dept`. Then, print any line.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, but I would like it very much if : you could explain the answer so I can learn from it. Also, does this have to replace sed in my loop or can I use this as is by typing awk before what you wrote ?

Comment: This is an Awk script. You would do `awk '/Code Postal:/ { ... #etc } { print }' filename` to replace your current bash script.  I'm not sure it does what you want, though; if you have two files where one contains line numbers, the script will need to be a little different.  Maybe you could still clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess as to what you are trying to accomplish.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { # Store line numbers in a[]
    a[$1] = $1; next }
   FNR in a { m=1 } # We are in match range
   /^------$/ { m=0 }  # Separator: we are out of range
   m && /^Adresse.*Code postal:/ { c=substr($NF, 1, 2); $NF = 90000 }
   m && /^Tél\. :$/ { $0 = c }
   { print }' file_that_contains_line_numbers_I_want.txt filename > filename.new
```

This contains some common Awk idioms.  The following is a really brief sketch of the script in human terms.

`NR` is the current line number overall, and `FNR` is the file number within the current file.  When these are equal, it means you are reading the first input file.  In this case, we read the line number into the array `a` and skip to the next line.

If we are falling through, we are reading the second file.  When we see a line number which is present in `a`, we set the flag `m` to a true (non-zero) value to indicate that we are in a region where a substition should take place.  When we see the dashed lines, we clear it, because this marks the end of the current record.

Finally, if we are in one of the targeted records (`m` is true) we look for the patterns and perform the requested extraction and substitution.  `NF` is the number of fields in the current line, and `$` selects a field, so `$NF = 90000` replaces the last field on the line; and `$0` is the entire input line, so when we see `Tél. :` we replace the whole line with the extracted code.

At the end of the script, we print whatever we are reading; the `next` in the first block skips the rest of the script, so we are printing only when we are in the second file. The resulting output should (hopefully!) be the result you require.

This should be orders of magnitude faster than reading the same file over and over again, and should work as long as the first file contains less than millions of line numbers (assuming modern hardware; if you have a really small machine with limited memory and no swap, maybe tens of thousands).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer and explain the answer aswell. I have somewhat understood your code, except the {c=substr($NF, 1, 2); $NF = 90000} part, because what I've read about substr is : substr(string,position,length) and I do not know about $NF; also the grymoire.com indicates that awk has a field limit of 99 fields per line, so maybe the $NF = 90000 is wrong ? If you thought that 90000 is constant in the text, I'm sorry to have not made myself clear enough.

Comment: Yeah, `NF` is the number of fields on the current line and so `$NF` addresses the last field -- if there are six fields then `NF` is 6 and `$6` addresses the sixth field on the line.  We are replacing the value of the last field, not changing its index; so we replace (say) 91234 with 90000, and also keeping the first two digits of the original value in `c` before doing this replacement.

Comment: Apparently you don't want to replace `$NF` at all, and the post code is not the last field, so that part of the code is not applicable to your question in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be what you want, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*Code Postal: *([0-9][0-9])/,a){$0=$0 ORS a[1]} !/^Tél/' file
```

or gawk or mawk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/.*Code Postal: *([0-9][0-9]).*/,"&\n\\1",1)} !/^Tél/' file
Nom: some text
Société: some text
Adresse: some text and numb3rs Code Postal: 90000 SOME TEXT
90
numbers
Fax :
numbers
"----------------------"
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
Nom: some text
Société: some text
Adresse: some text and numb3rs Code Postal: 90000 SOME TEXT
Tél. :
numbers
Fax :
numbers
"----------------------"
```

The above matches the stated regexp, saves the captured 2 digits in array a[1] and adds that preceded by a newline (ORS) to the end of the current line before printing that and any other line that doesn't start with `Tél`.

Read Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you'll be doing any text manipulation in UNIX.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works too ! Could you take some time to explain to me your code so I can learn to use awk better ?